# How to filter array of child array in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I filter my array by child array value? The example I have the following API request array and want to build a new array only with id 2 which have name = Other Name because my filter is set to Other Name

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "attendees": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "Some Name",
          "address": "mail@some"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "attendees": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "Other Name",
          "address": "mail@other"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do `foreach` and fill a new array `if(name == selected name)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $array as $k=>$v )
{
    if($array[$k]['id']==2 && $array[$k]['name'] == selected name){
         //make new array here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead forach you can think about Laravel collection, convert array to collection and then use `filter` method. Example:

```php
    $collection = collect([
        [
            "id" => 1,
            "attendees"=> [
            [
                "emailAddress" => [
                "name"=> "Some Name",
                "address"=> "mail@some"
                ]
            ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "attendees" => [
                [
                    "emailAddress"=> [
                    "name"=> "Other Name",
                    "address"=> "mail@other"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $filter = "Other Name";
    $filtered = $collection->filter( function( $value, $key ) use ( $filter ) {
        $attendees = collect( $value[ "attendees" ] );
        
        $filteredAttendees = $attendees->filter( function( $value, $key ) use ( $filter ){
            return $value["emailAddress"]["name"] === $filter;
        } );
        
        return count( $filteredAttendees ) > 0;
    });

    dd( $filtered->toArray( ));
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. How can I use this solution if I get an api request json?

Comment: You can decode json and convert to collection ```collect( json_decode($json, true) );```